# Shell Script for renaming and relocating the files

Tags: linux, file, shell, directory

I am working on something and need to solve the following. I am giving a analogous version of mine problem.

Say we have a music directory, in which there are 200 directories corresponding to different movies. In each movie directory there are some music files.

Now, say a file music.mp3 is in folder movie.mp3 . I want to make a shell script such that it renames the file to movie_music.mp3 and put it in some folder that I mention to it. Basically, all the files in the subdirectories are to be renamed and to be put in a new directory.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script receives two arguments: the source folder and the destination folder. It will move every file under any directory under the source directory to the new directory with the new filename:

```
#!/bin.sh
echo "Moving from $1 to $2"
for dir in "$1"/*; do
  if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
      if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "${file} -> $2/`basename "$dir"`_`basename "${file}"`"
        mv "${file}" "$2"/`basename "$dir"`_`basename "${file}"`
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

Here is a sample:

```
bash move.sh dir dir2
Moving from dir to dir2
dir/d1/f1 -> dir2/d1_f1
dir/d1/f2 -> dir2/d1_f2
dir/d2/f1 -> dir2/d2_f1
dir/d2/f2 -> dir2/d2_f2
```

Comment: can it accommodate spaces as well in the names of directories and files alike

Comment: the script is giving me following error : songs/ZINDA/Kabhi Muskura Ke.mp3 -> test/ZINDA_Kabhi Muskura Ke.mp3
mv: target `Ke.mp3' is not a directory

Comment: No, it breaks on spaces because `basename` is not properly quoted. More correct would be `mv -v -- "$file" "$2/$(basename -- "$dir")_$(basename -- "$file")"` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Bash:

```
newdir=path/to/new_directory;
find . -type d |while read d; do
  find "$d" -type f -maxdepth 1 |while read f; do
    movie="$(basename "$d" |sed 's/\(\..*\)\?//')"
    mv "$f" "$newdir/$movie_$(basename $f)";
  done;
done
```

Comment: There is no restriction that files are mp3. They can be of any media type like wav, mpg.. etc.

Comment: @abhishekgupta92 I updated the script to look for all files in each directory under the current directory, and move them to `$newdir`. You have to be aware though that if you move all these files into a single directory you are running the risk of losing files. You can minimize the risk by renaming the files (say, `s/\//_-_/g`), but that won't eliminate the risk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following directory tree:

```
./movie1:
movie1.mp3

./movie2:
movie2.mp3
```

The following one-liner will create 'mv' commands you can use:

```
find ./ | grep "movie.*/" | awk '{print "mv "$1" "$1}' | sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1_/'
```

**EDIT:**

If your directory structure contains only the relevant directories, you can expand use the following grep instead:

```
grep "\/.*\/.*"
```

Notice it looks file anything with at least one directory and one file. If you have multiple inner directories, it won't be good enough.

Comment: no der is nothing like movie1 .. say a movie named Spider Man, and another a movie named Titanic.

Comment: It is not taking care of spaces in the file. maybe renaming the files first so as to remove the spaces and replace them with dashes should help.