# How can I replace multiple PHP files in different directories with an updated PHP file using PHP

Tags: php

How can I replace multiple PHP files in different directories with the same PHP file using PHP for example, How do I replace all the `index.php` files in Example 1 with the `index.php` file in Example 2

Example 1 url values

```
/files/user-2/a/index.php
/files/user-12/a/index.php
/files/user-23/a/index.php
/files/user-232/a/index.php
/files/user-2232/a/index.php
```

Example 2 url values

```
/files/user-2/a/index.php
/files/user-12/a/index.php
/files/user-23/a/index.php
/files/user-232/a/index.php
/files/user-2232/a/index.php
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want to rename the files using a php script from the command line?

Comment: I want to replace all the old index.php files with an updated version of the new index.php file

Comment: This thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853113/shell-script-for-renaming-and-relocating-the-files/3853166#3853166

Comment: @Am I dont want to rename the file I want to add a new one with new php scripts to the old ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the rename function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php )

To use it, begin by parsing the dir content :

```
function renameFilesInDir($dirName) {

    $dir = opendir($dirName);

    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {

        if (is_file($dirName.$file)) {

            // Rename the File  

        }

    }

    closedir($dir);

}
```

Good Luck !

Comment: I dont want to rename the file I want to add a new one with new php scripts to the old ones